# Can Digital Ocean docker container registries be used with Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, digital-ocean

I'm attempting to pull an image down from a Digital Ocean container registry. The registry requires authentication via an API token (not username/password), and I can't see how to do that with the Jenkins API.

```
 docker.withRegistry("registry.digitalocean.com/example-registry") {
     def image = docker.image("my-image:latest")
 }
```

**Is it possible to connect to the Digitial Ocean container registry using the Jenkins API?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally discovered that you have to **add a new username/password credential** in Jenkins and **use the Digital Ocean auth token as both the username and password** (rather than the auth token as a secret).